# Getting "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 165: DB_ADDR: unbound variable" while creating keycloak container

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am trying to create a docker container for keycloak. But when I try the below command in docker quickstart terminal:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

I am getting the below error:

```
/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 165: DB_ADDR: unbound variable
```

Upon researching a bit, I came to know that I need to pass `DB_ADDR` in the command also. So I tried the below command now:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_ADDR=keycloak-db -e DB_VENDOR=h2 jboss/keycloak
```

But still I am getting the same error. I don't really know what I am doing wrong. Please if anyone can help me here. Thankyou all.

Comment: Your command looks right to me. I was looking at the script here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh and if that's the right script, then the only way to get to line 165 is if db_vendor is postgres (through the append_port_db_addr function). So that seems weird. Maybe you're better at reading shell scripts than I am.

Comment: I got this error when running examples from https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ where the env variables for `docker run` are defined AFTER the name of the image like here `docker run --name keycloak --net keycloak-network jboss/keycloak -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=password`. If you place the `jboss/keycloak` at the end it worked for me. The examples from the question are however ok for me.

Answer (score 5):

Update the script as below:

```
docker run \
-p 8080:8080 \
-e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
-e DB_VENDOR=h2 \
-e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
-it jboss/keycloak:latest
```